# How to dynamically weave in Spring interceptors

Tags: java, spring, dynamic, aop

Once I weave in an interceptor, link in springframework, JVM will put the interceptor code around the target method in byte code immediately. So no matter the interceptor is need to be or not, it will be executed. Is there any way that I can control whether an interceptor to be woven in or not?

Comment: Do you mean "weave" instead of "wave"?

Comment: I have fixed a few of your spelling errors and rephrased to subject so as to more precisely state what you want to find out. James, please correct your own question by editing it the next time, do not wait for others to do that. As for your question: Please show some code and Spring configuration in order to make your concrete problem reprodueable. StackOverflow is mainly about code.